# How do I setup user security in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I have added functionality to my web app to allow someone to create an account with a password, which is then hashed and stored.

I would like to be able to allow the user to login to my site and use the pages within that check the user has access. Then after a period of time the session will expire and the user has to log in again.

It would also be good to have a logout button.

I am just wondering what is the best way to setup this kind of security as I have not done it before like this.

Comment: The simplest is probably [Forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That wheel that you are making is nice for sure, but why not use one that has been invented already?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

As for sessions, you can use `Session["NameOfSession"]` to create a variable, don't forget to use `Session.Abandon()` though when a user logs out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.ASPX

Comment: Well yes you're right but essentially I did copy most of my code anyway, just customised the database etc. When you say use a session, do you mean just something like Session[IsLoggedIn] which is set after login and checked on every page?

Comment: Yes, but I recommend putting a simple User object (roles etc) into it, and then checking if it has a value to indicate if they have permission/are logged in. You will find that more useful

Answer (score 0):

As HTTP is offline protocol then there should be some extra-data being sent between client and server that makes server know you are logged on every request. The thing like this is cookie file that holds this information. On every request server checks this data and decides if you've already logged or not. Once you find the user's name and pass are OK you create this file, set its lifetime and attach to server response. After this the client browser will automatically send it to your server with each request. Once file is expired it will be automatically deleted by client browser.
You can maintain this functionality by hands or trust to FormsAuthentication.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? I am unsure of how to create that file.

Comment: @connersz this is for FormsAuthentiocation: example   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.100).aspx and overview http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4(v=vs.100).aspx .If you want to implement it by yourself then read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194(v=vs.100).aspx . I would suggest to use integrated FormsAuthentocation.